# Javascript increasing animation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following part of code:

```
<script>
$(function() {
  var ele = $('#clients');
  var clr = null;
  var rand = 0;
  (loop = function() {
    clearTimeout(clr);
    (inloop = function() {
      ele.html(rand+=1);
      if(clr==1000) {
        return;
      }
      clr = setTimeout(inloop, 5);
    })(); 
  })();
});
</script>
```

How can i create a second function which will count until another number in the same page? Tried to do a few tests without success..

I tried this:

```
<script>
$(function() {
  var ele = $('#products');
  var clr = null;
  var rand = 0;
  (loop = function() {
     clearTimeout(clr);
    (inloop = function() {
      ele.html(rand+=1);
      if(clr==151) {
        return;
      }
      clr = setTimeout(inloop, 5);
    })();
  })();
});
</script>
```

But the first function counts only until 2.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried already?

Comment: I have updated the initital post.

Comment: @Georgy "How can i create a second function which will count until another number in the same page?", what do you mean by "another number in the same page"?

Comment: The initial function counts from 0 to 1000. I want to add a new function which will count from 0 to 500 (for example) which will be called from another part of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems:

1. You shouldn't use the return value of `setTimeout` like this - it's not guaranteed to be an incrementing integer, and even when it is, it's global to the page and you can't reset it. Since you're already keeping a count in `rand`, you can use that to terminate your loop instead of `clr`.
2. As pointed out by @putvande, you're overwriting a global `inloop` variable with your second loop, and they will therefore interfere with each other - you need to declare a local variable.

Also your `clearTimeout` isn't doing anything useful, and you don't actually need your `clr` variable...

```js
$(function() {
  var ele = $('#clients');
  var rand = 0;
  var inloop;

  (loop = function() {
    (inloop = function() {
      ele.html(rand+=1);
      if(rand==1000) {
        return;
      }
      setTimeout(inloop, 5);
    })(); 
  })();
});

$(function() {
  var ele = $('#products');
  var rand = 0;
  var inloop;
  
  (loop = function() {
    (inloop = function() {
      ele.html(rand+=1);
      if(rand==151) {
        return;
      }
      setTimeout(inloop, 5);
    })();
  })();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="clients"></div>
<div id="products"></div>
```

Now you can extract the common code and reuse it:

```js
function countTo(ele, count) {
  var rand = 0;
  var inloop;

  (inloop = function() {
    ele.html(rand += 1);
    if(rand == count) {
      return;
    }
    setTimeout(inloop, 5);
  })(); 
}

$(function() {
  countTo($('#clients'), 1000);
  countTo($('#products'), 151);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="clients"></div>
<div id="products"></div>
```

Comment: welcome - but as @putvande also mentioned, it's better to extract the common code and reuse - see the second snippet I just added

Comment: thank you very much, i updated the code and added the time of the loop as a variable too.

Answer (score 0):

It's because `inloop` is not defined anywhere and will therefore be defined on a global scope. In your second function, you override this variable. So your first function runs once, and then your second one will run until it stops.

So you should define the `inloop` inside your `loop` function:

```
...
(loop = function() {
    var inloop;
    clearTimeout(clr);
    (inloop = function() {
        ...
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hrx7uk0w/)

But what you probably want is to rewrite it so you could just call your same functionality twice with some parameters.

Comment: I tried to use this but the first script is counting until 501.